# How to start a new activity passing an image uri

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an activity with a button that opens a dialog allowing to choose between Taking a picture or Selecting a picture from gallery coded like that:

```
private void showDialogToSelectAFile() {
    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder dialog = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this);

    dialog.setTitle("Select a file or take a picture")
            .setMessage("Choose one of the options")
            .setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //do nothing
                }
            }).setPositiveButton("Take a picture", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            openCameraToTakePictureIntent();
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Select a file from your gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            openGalleryIntent();
        }
    }).show();
}
```

Then it runs the following intent to do the selected action:

```
private void openCameraToTakePictureIntent() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Method for Intent Camera started");
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.emergence.domain.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

}
```

Now I want to start a new activity that will display the picture and allow modifications on this picture so I though I'd pass the URI in an "onActivityResult" but I can't figure out how to do it.

So far it doesn't crash, I can select an image or take a picture but of course when I do so, it only goes back to the activty doing nothing except hopefully storing the image in the file.

**My questions:**
Is there a better way to proceed to pass an image to a new activity while keeping it full quality ?
If not, how can I pass this URI and retrieve the image in the new activity ?
Is my image actually stored in the file I created ?

Here is my createImageFile function in case it's relevant:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Thanks for your help

EDIT:

I have updated the onActivityResult as follow:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ModifyPictureActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, currentPhotoPath);
        startActivity(intent);

}
```

I created this new activity that only has an ImageView in which I want to display the picture but I can't find the right method to set the image to the Extras. So far I have this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_modify_picture);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.getExtras();

    image = findViewById(R.id.image);

    image.setImageURI(???);

}
```

Should I try to set the image with another method than "setImageURI"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have two options:

1. If you want a small-sized image, you can get it in the `onActivityResult` callback via decoding the bitmap
2. Since you are passing in the uri, with the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` key, `MediaStore` will save the file to that location. So in the `onActivityResult` callback, you just check if the message is `ok` and the request code corresponds, after that you can read from the file with the URI you've passed in with the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` key

Comment: I did Override onActivityResult but I really can't figure out what to put inside even after reading the android developper. I guess the "data" is my picture, but how do I start the other activity with that data is my problem.

Comment: Ok I'm closing in thanks to you, I just need one last help. I edited my post with my onActivityResult function.

Comment: You should use `getIntent().getParcelableExtra<Uri>(SOME_CUSTOME_KEY)`, also I suggest you to use a custom key, not the `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` for this.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I finally made it work with your advices.

Answer (score 0):

in onActivtyResult check, if URI not null pass it to your new activity

```
    Intent intent = Intent(this, your activity)
    intent.putExtra("uri", uri)
    startActivity(intent)
```

then in (your new activity) use these lines to get Uri

```
   Bitmap photo= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(intent.getStringExtra("uri"))
   imageView.setImageBitmap(photo)
```

NOTE: pass uri as string